# Run Laravel on another URL root path http://example.xom/laravel_proj1 and http://example.xom/laravel_proj2

Tags: laravel, apache, url-routing

I want to use `Laravel` projects at the same time. How you can do it? For example one project at

http://example.xom/laravel_proj1
and another on
http://example.xom/laravel_proj2

Configuration: `Laravel 7 / 8` and `Apache`

Update: This is 2 different Projects. But are there some problems if I use this 2 equals Projects. Upsides of MySQL Datables of course.

```
File: /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts/APPNAME-vhost.conf

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 _default_:80>
  ServerAlias *
  DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/projects/APPNAME/public
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/projects/APPNAME/public">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you want to run two different projects on the same host, or should the same project be opened on both urls? (`/laravel_proj1` and `/laravel_proj2`)

Comment: Can you show us your current approach? Did you configure vhosts?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you work with subdomains to have multiple laravel projects running at the same time. This means that one instance runs at first.example.com and the other at second.example.com. In my opinion what you are trying is more a workaround if you only have one vhost running.

So I would have two vhost files like you have now. One like:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 _default_:80>
  ServerAlias first.example.com
  DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/projects/first/public
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/projects/first/public">
  ...
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 _default_:80>
  ServerAlias second.example.com
  DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/projects/second/public
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/projects/second/public">
  ...
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you would add both subdomains to your hosts file. I don't know where that one is located but in there you would have to add:

```
127.0.0.1 first.example.com
127.0.0.1 second.example.com
```

This is not exactly how I do it now, but I think it could be a good starting point. You also need to activate your vhosts and restart apache.

Comment: FYI: You can also use totally different domains for the two laravel projects.

Comment: Hey, that's cool. This does not answer my question exactly, but solves exactly my problem